# Kernel module to monitor syscalls?

Tags: linux, module, kernel

I would like to create a kernel module from scratch that latches to a user session and monitors each system call made by processes belonging to that user.

I know what everyone is thinking - "use strace" - but I'd like to have some of my own logging and analysis with the data I collect, and strace has some issues -  an application could use "mmap" to write to a file without the file contents ever appearing as the arguments of an "open" system call, or an application without any write permission may create coredumps to copy sensitive data.

I want to be able to handle these special cases and do some of my own logging. I wonder though - how can I route all syscalls through my module? Is there any way to do that without touching  the kernel code?

Thanks

Comment: You should use the `ptrace` syscall (which indeed is used by `strace` and `gdb`). Good luck, you'll need some. But you probably don't need to code any kernel module, just to develop an application using `ptrace` a big lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done something similar in the past by using a kernel module to patch the system call table. Each patched function did something like the following:

```
patchFunction(/*params*/)
{
   // pre checks
   ret = origFunction(/*params*/);
   // post checks
   return ret;
}
```

Note that when you start mucking around in the kernel data structures, your module becomes version dependent. The kernel module will probably have to be compiled for the specific kernel version you are installing on.

Also note, this is a technique employed by many rootkits so if you have security software installed it may try to prevent you from doing something like this.

Comment: This was definitely in the right direction. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=139406 was the best guide I could find. With some mucking around I got to where I can hijack ANY syscall. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

I don't have the exact answer to your question, but I red a paper a couple of days ago and it may be useful for you:

http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/moona/students/Y2157230.pdf/